Safari loads pages but won't follow links
Since update to MacOS Sonoma 14.5, Safari will load pages without problems but will not follow links of any kind. For example, on a page in Amazon, I can't click on "Read More." On other pages, clicking links to go to another page does nothing. I'm only having this issue in Safari. Very rarely the page works okay, but 98% of the time, it doesn't work. I'm using Safari on a 2023 MacBook Air M2 with updated OS.

Disable all Safari extensions in its settings and test. If it works now, re-enable them one, or a few, at a time until you isolate the culprit.

Can you try creating a new local user and see if it still happens in that user's safari environment?
